# ADFS web server setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs

I am very very new to ADFS 2.0, i have been using Domain trust and i am doing some research on ADFS 2.0 to convert my current web app to ADFS 2.0, question i have is

> 1. Does the Web server needs to be on a perimeter network facing internet? or i can use web proxy or if federation proxy supports that built in for web server too.
> 2. Does my SSL cert needs to be on my IIS or i can host it on my load balancer?

1. Also do i need to have .net 3.0 and above to use adfs with asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ADFS, you can install an ADFS proxy that is accessible to the Internet. This communicates with an instance of ADFS which can be behind a firewall.

ADFS requires a "Service communications" certificate which typically uses the SSL certificate of the IIS that hosts ADFS.

I detailed the WIF requirements in my other answer to you.

ADFS requires Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 together with Service Pack 1.

Comment: how about the web server does it have to be in perimeter network or can be inside the network

Comment: You mean the web server running the ASP.NET application? Depends on who accesses it. For external users, need to be accessible to the Internet. For internal users only, can be behind a firewall.